# I've changed all the connection strings I could find in my company old ASP.NET application but it still points to the same database

Tags: sql, asp.net, iis, razor, connection-string

I'm trying to change the database of a local application but it keeps pointing to the old database (I renamed some tables to check if it breaks after and it does). 
I've searched for the connections strings inside the application and renamed them all to the new database, but it keeps pointing to the old one. I know the app is being refreshed cause I'm able to break it by removing lines from the web.config. No matter what I do, it keeps pointing to the old database.

**Does IIS keeps connection strings cached somewhere? Any clues where the connection strings might be?**

Another interesting thing is that even when I remove all the old connection strings the app still works. The app is using ASP.NET and IIS.

Comment: It would be possible restart? or, have you execute iisreset command?

Comment: I already did :/. I also recycled the application pool and deleted .net framework temp files, changed the IIS connection string, the app still points to the old database.

Comment: Think you're going to have to look at the source code to figure out where it is getting its connection strings from.

Comment: I think you are probably right. It is just weird that I would search the old database instance name inside the source code and it doesn't show results. I don't know how it would connect to it without the database name or path inside the source code.

Comment: Are you using EF to handle database? If so, change connection string would not work in some case. Then you need to check your code. IIS itself will not cache or prevent refreshing connection string.